# How can I get the final list of resources with concatenated names and real names of similar resources created by loop?

Tags: templates, azure-resource-manager

For example, I have Azure Resource Manager template which uses concatenation and describes several similar resources with automatical name generation (vm_1, vm_2, vm_3) with command.
I do not want to parse template by myself to know real final names of resources.
I want plain final list of resources. Something like that:

Template (in pseudocode)

```
var1="my"
var2="res"
my_resource_name=var1 + "_" + var2
my_VMs=vm_image*3
```

Final plain list:

```
my_resource_name=my_res
my_VM_1
my_VM_2
my_VM_3
```

Is it possible with some ready to use tool, script, etc?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the above that you are deploying the resources using the arm template . I have written the below script to pull the resources that were deployed in a single deployment.

For the below script to work you need to pass the deployment Name & resource group parameters as input

```
connect-azaccount
$list= az deployment group  show -n <deploymentName> -g <resource-groupName> --query "properties.outputResources" 

$listArray = $list| ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($list in $listArray)
{
    az resource show --id $list.id --query '{Name:name,resource:type}'

}
```

Alternatively, you can use the below cmdlet to pull the resources that were created & having the concatenation string(if concatenation string is constant) in the name of the resource.

```
Get-AzResource -Name <concatestring>* | Format-TableName,ResourceGroupName,Type,ResourceId
```

if you know the resource type you can use the below command

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts -Name <concatestring>*
```